# Python code driver=webdriver.Firefox() couldn't understand

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I know i am asking a very silly question but couldn't find the solution so asking here.

Need to understand below line

```
driver=webdriver.FirefoxDriver()
```

From java I understand `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver()` where `webdriver` is an interface and pointing to class `FirefoxDriver`.

in python i couldn't understand this line `driver=webdriver.Firefox()`.

Is `Firefox` is a class and locating inside the folder `webdriver`? if yes then where it is mention in official python document I couldn't find out this description anywhere please help.

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at some basic Python tutorials that introduce topics such as "modules" and "classes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is: NO, `Firefox()` is not a Class in Selenium. It's just an alias for another class called `webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver` which can be found on the official repository of Selenium on Github [right here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py).

How did I know that? Simply, from this `__init__.py` [file](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/__init__.py) on the official repo. This file helps you create shortcuts for your internal classes. Not exactly, but you get the idea!!

If you opened this file, you can see clearly in the first line that `Firefox` is just an alias for `webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver`

Here is the first few lines of this file:

```
from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
from .firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile  # noqa
from .firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions  # noqa
from .chrome.webdriver import WebDriver as Chrome  # noqa
...
```

From this, we can dedicate that:

- `FirefoxProfile` is an alias for `webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.FirefoxProfile`
- `FirefoxOptions` is an alias for `webdriver.firefox.options.Options`
- `Chrome` is an alias for `webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver`
- And so on...

Hope this answers your question!!

Comment: really very well explained, wonderful explanation ..thanks a ton @Anwarvic.